# Set an array to Chart.SeriesCollection().Values

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I've been seen some examples here on Stackoverflow and other sites a way to set the values for a chart using an array but this is not working for me:

```
d_ppt_output.Slides(1).Shapes("P_Cronograma_Realizado").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Array(20)
```

When I check .Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Values, the value 20 is not set and it says that there is no variables. Why this not work for me?
PS: I already have a chart in my PPT and here I am just changing the value. I can change by calling the spreadsheet but I'd like to change directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in theory. However, I see SeriesCollection(1) in your code and SeriesCollection(3) in the text. Array() has to contain all the values you plan to present on the chart, so if you want to see only one 20, then it's OK.

**Update 1**

Could you try the following?

```
Dim varValues(1 To 1) as Variant
varValues(1) = 20
d_ppt_output.Slides(1).Shapes("P_Cronograma_Realizado").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = varValues
```

**Update 2**

So, you have a chart which is embedded from Excel. To edit it you need Excel. An alternative is two create a chart inside PowerPoint, so you won't need Excel.

Comment: Hi z32a7ul! about the SeriesCollection(3) I wrote wrong just here on the text. It's very strange. When I inspect the variable, it shows the value I already have but when I set Array(..) and inspect the variable again, there is nothing and it says that there is no variables. Do you think that it is happening because I am using an already done chart from a PPT?

Comment: And what do you see in the Watch Window under ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values and ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula and ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).FormulaLocal?

Comment: Man, I found out an interesting ans strange thing. Currently I set this value by calling an excel spreadsheet and while I was testing/debugging the code you suggested, after execute that I called the .Shapes("P_Cronograma_Realizado").Chart.ChartData.Activate which opens Excel, than this made the value 20 of the variable appear! It looks like something needs to be refresh, but .Activate is not a good one as I don't want to call Excel...

Comment: I checked .Formula and .FormulaLocal and it says that "the method 'Formula' of object 'Series' failed "

Comment: But how I create a chart in PowerPoint without embedding an Excel?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the user interface: On the Ribbon go to Insert and click on Chart. You could do it with a macro but since your code only modifies the existing chart, it is not worth the effort.

Comment: Basically I have a PPT as a template with some fields and charts, than in a Excel and Access I fill up some information that I later I generate a presentation based on that template.

Comment: Well, for now I will keep updating the chart by calling Excel. I'd like to now call as it would make faster the execution.

Comment: And why don't you replace the charts in your ppt template?

Comment: I mean why don't you insert new charts in your ppt template (which don't refer to an embedded excel) and delete the old ones?

Comment: Oh, ok.. but how can I add a chart not embedded to Excel? Because when I add a new chart on PPT, the excel opens automatically to add values... Is there a way to not "link" to Excel?

Comment: If you add it in ppt, it won't be linked to excel. Well, I think I used a wrong term previously. It will be embedded and not linked.

Comment: Wait hahaha. Let me see if I understood, so I add a chart via VBA/Code instead adding manually to PPT template file? Is it that? Because I currently added manually a Chart on PPT file and format it manually. So do you mean I have to create a new chart object via code and make all the format via code, right? So by this way it will not be linked to Excel, correct?

Comment: Not exactly. You can create manually the chart using PPT's Ribbon or via VBA using PPT's ActivePresentation.Slides(X).Shapes.AddChart. However, I think the latter is not worth it if you want to do it only once. After the chart is added you can format it either manually, or via VBA; I think formatting only once is easier manually. And when you saved your template file, then you can modify the chart with the VBA macro for each instance of output to create, I suppose you will do that many times, so using VBA is worth it.

Comment: OK, I think I understood, I will try that. Thanks!